# $C^*$-algebra generated by those operators that are bounded on every $\ell_p$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, banach-spaces, c-star-algebras

Suppose $T: c_{00} \to c_{00}$ is a linear map such that, when regarded as an infinite matrix, there is a uniform bound on the $\ell_1$-norms of its columns, and a uniform bound on the $\ell_1$-norms of its rows.
That is,
$\newcommand{\Bdd}{{\mathcal B}}\newcommand{\Cst}{{\rm C}^*}$
$\sup_j \sum_i |T_{ij}| <\infty$ and $\sup_i \sum_j |T_{ij}| < \infty \;. $
One can show that if $C$ is the maximum of these two sups, then $\Vert T(\xi)\Vert_p\leq C\Vert\xi\Vert_p$ for all $\xi\in c_{00}$ and all $p\in [1,\infty]$.

Now let $B_{00}$ be the set of all such $T$; this is a subalgebra of ${\rm Lin}(c_{00})$ and by abuse of notation we can regard it as a subalgebra of every $\Bdd(\ell_p)$. In particular it's a $*$-subalgebra of $\Bdd(\ell_2)$, so its norm closure $B_2$ is a $\Cst$-subalgebra of $\Bdd(\ell_2)$.

The algebra $B_2$ is currently somewhat mysterious to me, and I am hoping that people reading MO may recognize it, or know of it under some different name. Note that $B_2$ is not all of $\Bdd(\ell_2)$, because there are operators in $\Bdd(\ell_2)$ that cannot be approximated in norm by $\ell_1$-preserving operators (cf. [this old MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30353/)).

If $G$ is any countable discrete group then, regarding $B_2$ as a subalgebra of $\Bdd(\ell_2(G))$, a quick check shows that it contains $\lambda(\ell_1(G))$ and hence contains $\Cst_r(G)$. Since $\Cst_r(G)$ need not be exact, $B_2$ can't be exact (and hence, as was pointed out in the comments, it can't have the cb approximation property).

**Q1.** Does $B_2$ contain a copy (up to c.b. isomorphism, say) of the $\Cst$-algebraic direct product $\prod_k M_k({\bf C})$? (This would imply that $B_2$ is not an exact $\Cst$-algebra, although we knew this already.)

**Q2.** Is there some identification of $B_2$ with a "known type" of $\Cst$-algebra? E.g. some kind of crossed product of the form $\ell^\infty(X)\rtimes G$ for some group $G$ acting on a countable set $X$?

**Q3.** Does $B_2$ have the (metric) approximation property?

Comment: Probably, you mean $\leq 1$ instead of $< \infty$.

Comment: Nice questions.  I guess that no one has considered any of them. I asked Szankowski to look at Q3 in case an "easy" modification of his argument for $B(H)$ would show that $B_2$ fails the AP.

Comment: Note that if $B_2$ contains a sub-C*-algebra isomorphic to $X=(\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty M_n)_{\ell_\infty}$ then $B_2$ lacks the AP. Indeed, $X$ is Banach-space isomorphic to $\mathscr{B}(\ell_2)$ and the latter space lacks the AP by a result of Szankowski. On the other hand, $X$ is injective in the category of operator systems, so in particular $B_2$ would contain a complemented subspace without the AP.

Comment: I think you already answered parts of Q1 and Q3.  You mention that  $B_2$ has a non-exact subalgebra. Since exactness passes to subalgebras, $B_2$ can't be exact.  Since exactness implies CBAP, $B_2$  cannot have the CBAP.

Comment: @CalebEckhardt Well in Q1 I really wanted to know if there is a more obvious non-exact operator space inside $B_2$.

Comment: That's because I said something wrong.  CBAP implies exactness.

Comment: I think the algebra $B_2$ contains every diagonal operator in $B(\ell_2)$ and also every permutation unitary. It would follow that $B_2$ also contains the uniform Roe algebra of every countable discrete group. Maybe it is known if uniform Roe algebras (of non-exact groups) contain $\prod_k M_k(\mathbb{C})$ ?

Comment: @HannesThiel Thanks for this observation. Having thought about this question a little more, and reading your observation, I now wonder if $B_2$ equals the uniform Roe algebra of the "full permutation group of ${\bf N}$"